# Want to send images using node.js and socket.io in android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets

I am Creating a chat app between two users now I can do Simple text chat with different users using node.js and socket.io. Now problem arises here as I have to send image in chat application and after searching for whole long day I am not able to get perfect node.js in which I can send image in chat app. So I want to know is it possible to send image using node.js. Here is my simple node.js file for sending simple text message from one user to another.

```
socket.on('privateMessage', function(data) {
    socket.get('name', function (err, name) {
        if(!err) {
            // get the user from list by its name to get its socket, 
            // then emit event privateMessage
            // again here we want to make you clear
            // that every single client connection has its own
            // unique SOcket Object, we need to get this Socket object
            // to communicate with every other client. The socket variable
            // in this scope is the client who wants to send the private 
            // message but the socket of the receiver is not know.
            // Get it from the saved list when connectMe handlers gets called
            // by each user.
            onLine[data.to].emit('newPrivateMessage',{from:name, msg:data.msg, type:'Private Msg'})
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Base64 version of your image and send it like this:

```
onLine[data.to].emit('newPrivateMessage',{from:name, img:data.img.toString('base64'), type:'Private Msg'})
```

.. and then on the client side receive it and create an image

```
socket.on("newPrivateMessage", function(data) {
    if (data.img) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.img;

        // Do whatever you want with your image.
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

The following is a snippet taken from the link I've commented below. As you can see it takes the image from the `input`, `read`s it and sends to the server. After that you can send the same data from the server to another client.

For the full example, please read [the article](http://ckazbah.com/2014/03/26/websockets-with-socket-io-simple-image-file-upload/).

## JavaScript (client)

```
...

$('#imageFile').on('change', function(e) {
   var file = e.originalEvent.target.files[0],
     reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(evt) {
     var jsonObject = {
         'imageData': evt.target.result
       }

     // send a custom socket message to server
     socket.emit('user image', jsonObject);
   };

   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 });

...
```

## HTML

```
...

Image file: <input type="file" id="imageFile" /><br/>

...
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is one example I have found:

## Java (client)

```
File file = new File("path/to/the/image");

try {
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);

    // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
    String imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

The above snippet shows how to read the file and encode the data into a `base64` string. So then you can send it just like a string (I assume).

Here is the complete example: [How to convert Image to String and String to Image in Java?](http://myjeeva.com/how-to-convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java.html)

Also I have found [`encodeToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) function of `Base64.Encoder` (`java.util` package), which you can use.

Comment: Actually how to send from one user to another user. The example given by you is to send image from node.js to user and i want to send from user to another user using node.js

Comment: Can you please just tell me how to send image to node.js server?

Comment: Please take a look at the code here: http://ckazbah.com/2014/03/26/websockets-with-socket-io-simple-image-file-upload/

Comment: Can you please just tell me how to send the image to node.js server from json.

Comment: What do you mean by `from json`?

Comment: Sorry by emitting like socket.emit("img" "?"); Like what has to be send  to server as image should i send image path?

Comment: But how to do this from native android?

Comment: The last line is giving error.....The method encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[]) is undefined for the type

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Regarding the last error: maybe there's some package which should be imported. And also check out the last function I have provided above (`encodeToString`).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to simply [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode the image and send it through the text pipe. You would need to distinguish text and image messages with header information (Maybe send a JSON object?).